# Travis CI failing with `Link MyProject`

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, travis-ci

I'm trying to integrate Travis with my project.

This is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: objective-c

osx_image: xcode7.2

before_install:
  - rvm use system            
  - sudo gem install cocoapods -v '0.39.0'

script: 
    xctool -project MyProject.xcodeproj -scheme MyProject build -sdk iphonesimulator
```

All the classes are compiling without problem, but Travis is giving me this error:

```
✗ Link MyProject

ld: library not found for -lCoreDataManager
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
      1 errored, 1 warning (9118 ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `Cocoapods`.

That means you script should be pointing the **-workspace** and not the **-project**.

Also **MyProject.xcworkspace** instead of **MyProject.xcodeproj**:

e.g.

```
script: 
   xctool -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme MyProject build -sdk iphonesimulator
```

[I also wrote a post in my blog about Travis-CI.](https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/05/add-travis-ci-to-your-coding-challenge/)